# Reference variable in quasiquoted LLVM

Tags: haskell, happy

How do you pass a variable into a quasiquoted section?

I'm using [llvm-quote-general](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-general-quote-0.2.0.0) and would like to pass a `Type` into an instruction I'm building with the quasiquoter.

I can build an instruction from just text:

```
alloci64 :: Instruction
alloci64 = [lli|alloc i64|]
```

I'd like to be able to pass in a type. What is the syntax to do so?

```
alloc :: Type -> Instruction
alloc t = [lli|alloc t|]
```

I've tried all of the following, and none of them have worked. They result in `lexer error`s.

```
[lli|alloc $t|]
[lli|alloc $$t|]
[lli|alloc $t$|]
[lli|alloc $$t$$|]
```

The quasiquoter in the library was generated with happy. Looking through the source code, the closest thing I can find to a token in relation to anti quotation is the symbol `happy_dollar_dollar`, which doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

*Edit: I solved the problem for `Type`s; an example is `[lli|alloc $type:t]`*

#### Operands

I solved the problem with `Type`s, but still can't figure out how to anti-quote things in general. I'd like to use `Operand`s building an instruction. Trying to do so results in an error.

```
add' :: Operand -> Operand -> Instruction
add' a b = [lli|add $opr:a $opr:b|]
                    ^
                    parse error on `ANTI_OPR'
```

The [pre-happy source](https://github.com/tvh/llvm-general-quote/blob/master/src/LLVM/General/Quote/Parser/Lexer.x) suggests that all of the following, including `$opr:` should do something

```
<0> {
 "$dl:"           / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_dl }
 "$dlM:"           / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_dl }
 "$tt:"           / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_tt }
 "$ttM:"           / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_tt }
 "$def:"          / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_def }
 "$defM:"          / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_def }
 "$defs:"         / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_defs }
 "$defsM:"         / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_defs }
 "$bb:"           / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_bb }
 "$bbM:"           / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_bb }
 "$bbs:"          / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_bbs }
 "$bbsM:"          / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_bbs }
 "$instr:"        / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_instr }
 "$instrM:"        / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_instr }
 "$instrs:"       / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_instrs }
 "$instrsM:"       / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_instrs }
 "$type:"         / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_type }
 "$typeM:"         / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_type }
 "$opr:"          / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_opr }
 "$oprM:"          / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_opr }
 "$const:"        / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_const }
 "$constM:"        / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_const }
 "$id:"           / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_id }
 "$idM:"           / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_id }
 "$gid:"          / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_gid }
 "$gidM:"          / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_gid }
 "$param:"        / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_param }
 "$paramM:"        / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_param }
 "$params:"       / { allowAnti } { lexAnti Tanti_params }
 "$paramsM:"       / { allowAnti } { lexAntiM Tanti_params }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddling around some more, the following worked

```
alloc :: Type -> Instruction
alloc t = [lli|alloc $type:t|]
```

The string `"type"` was in [the source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-general-quote-0.2.0.0/docs/src/LLVM-General-Quote-Parser-Tokens.html) and other examples contain text like `$exp:e1` without explaining what it it.